# Are there any QO boxes with the neutral screws along the breakers like the Homeline?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel, electrical-distribution

I am having my panel replaced with a panel that has more real estate as well as having my Knob and Tube replaced.

Currently I have an older 24 Circuit/Spot Square D QO box. I would like to reuse some of the newer breakers in this box in the new box.

I would like to go with Square D again as from what I have read their reputation is very good and I like the plug on neutral.

I have read the QO boxes are more the Cadillac of boxes and the Homelines are not as good.

The issue I see though is, the Homeline boxes have the screw terminal for the neutral bus along the height of the box next to the breakers. This seems like a great feature for wire management and trace-ability.

The other advantage I see with this neutral bus is that circuit can easily be switched to CAFI as the neutral is already there and can just be moved to the breaker without having to splice the shortened neutral at the top neutral bus and extend it down.

The one feature I have seen in the QO line is the Qwik Grip. Again this seems like an amazing feature for adding circuits and manageability.

My question is:
Are there any QO boxes out there that have the neutral screws along the breakers like the Homeline?
From any experience, is having the neutral bus run along the breakers an advantage as I mentioned above?

Can anyone point me to a QO box with Qwik Grip and neutral bus along the breakers?

Comment: Step one, don't replace your exsisting panel - it's not a Federal Pacific or similar fire hazard. Depending on your upgrade, it can either feed a new panel as a sub (if you need more space, but not more total amps), or be fed from a new panel with a higher amp main, as a sub-panel (remove the neutral/ground bond on the sub-panel, in either case.) Point, rather than step, the second - convenience in wiring the panel is only a benefit for the few hours of the many decades of life of the panel. i.e. not a thing that matters at all far more than 99% of the time once it's wired up correctly once.

Answer (score 2):

### As it turns out, you can get what you want, but it's an extra piece

The QO and Homeline loadcenters use different designs for their plug-on neutrals.  The QO design has the screw terminals up against the mains while the neutral busbar extending down the breakers is plug-on only, while the Homeline plug-on neutral bars provide screw holes along their length.  Furthermore, the QO's bigger brother (the NQ) doesn't have any support for plug-on neutrals at all (this limits you to 60 slots, vs the 84 available in NQ).

However, someone at Square-D was thoughtful, because they make what are called *neutral extension kits* for the QO loadcenter line.  You'll need to order these from a supply house that stocks Square-D stuff (part numbers are QONK1 through QONK4 depending on how long you want the extension bars to be), but if you can get one of these kits in, this will give you something close to what you want, with extra neutral bars running alongside the breakers in the gutter.

Comment: Thanks ThreePhaseEel, this is what I was seeing and needed some confirmation. I'm really thinking of going with the Homeline even though I have to replace all my breakers because of the built in neutral along the length of the panel and also the fact as mentioned above breakers potentially being cheaper. 

It's such a hard decision when you are into this sort of thing and just not the average home owner who just "wants it to work".

Answer (score 1):

There are endless configurations of boxes, both QO and Homeline.  The usual problem is people shopping at a big-box store and being stuck with their joke of a selection.  Go to a real electrical supply house that frontlines Square D, they will be able to set you up with whatever you want.

Eaton has done the same thing with their lines: CH (former Cutler Hammer) is their Cadillac, and BR (former Bryant) is their tenant grade cheapie.  That doesn't always buy you better though, I had a Square D dealer show me how some Homeline breakers are simply the QO breakers in a larger case.

Now the problem with both their Cadillacs is they are 3/4" wide breakers.  And this *just makes it* technically more difficult to cram an AFCI, GFCI or other complex breaker into such a small space.  **That makes them *rather* more expensive.**

If cost is a factor, you might want to price *the entire package* of things you're buying now and things you intend to buy later.

There are other manufacturers.  Naturally the ones prominent on the bottom shelf of big-box are the tenant grade cheapies.  There are pro-grade panels too, but for *any* selection you'll need a real electrical supply.  In my search for pro-grade, reasonably available, and sensibly priced specialty breakers -- I keep hearing the name "Siemens".

Nothing says you need to trash your old panel.  You can keep it and make it a subpanel.  Depending on your wiring topology, you might not even need to move it!

Comment: Thanks Harper! I will need to look around for a Supply House. The only reason I do not want to go with a sub panel is the current panel is a mess (wires strung every which way, wires cut too short and stretched, etc) and I have to have the entire thing rewired anyway, and if I am having it all rewired, I'd rather just have everything in one place. Thanks again

Comment: Then make sure you get a panel that's big enough. Worst mistake you can make is trying to save money on a panel.  They are commonly available up to 60, and as high as 84 spaces.

Comment: @Harper -- when going above 60 spaces, it's cheaper to get 2 loadcenters, subfeed lugs, some 300kcmil Al, a fat nipple, and some locknuts than to splash out on a big commercial panelboard...(the Siemens BL breakers that go with the Siemens P1 'boards are hideous even compared to QO prices AFAICT, and the Square-D NQ 'boards themselves are a bit crazytalk esp. in high slot counts -- 84 slot NQ interiors often run near $2k from the numbers I've seen).

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that's true, anyway a 42 space panel will let you run up to 20 subpanels...

Answer (score 0):

QO breakers will not fit in a Homeline panel nd ceiling versa.

QO breaker panels are available with plug on neutral bars so you can add a GFCI AFCI breaker without a pigtail.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks that part is understood. That's one of the reasons I want to go with another QO box.